# Hoping for author and name of a particular novel/ like a submarine but in a superspace

Tags: story-identification, novel, hyperspace

Science fiction novel from 1980s or 1990s or 2000s.  People can go into a particular different space, said to be "above" our space, where distances are shorter. Particular ships can go "up" into this space and move undetected, and can shoot and kill ships in normal space.  Novel describes a patrol by one such ship. Reporter who has wrangled a tour on this on this ship witnesses successful military activity and crew undergoing various hair-raising situations and privations.  Self consciously based on WWII submarine novels and nonfiction such including *Run Silent, Run Deep* and real life WWII actions such as Darter and Dace.

Comment: Can you remember anything else? Any plot elements, names, genders, words or phrases? The more information we have, the easier it will be to find an answer.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I remembered the whole thing.  The book is called "Passage at arms" and it's by Glen Cook.   Journalist is ex Navy and has served on some kinds of more conventional ships but not these.  These ships are called "climbers".  With thanks for your reply and apologies for not remembering more earlier.

Answer (score 8):

### This is *Passage at Arms*

As confirmed by the querent, the novel *Passage at Arms* is the answer to this question.

**There's a "reporter"**:

> The reporter, the observer, ideally, remains neutral and detached.
>   However, I’ve altered the experiment simply by being here. I’ve tried
>   to be both remote and intimate, born Climber man and reporter. I’ve
>   failed. My shipmates, so young, came to Navy with near-virgin pasts.
>   Trying to mirror then: innocence, I’ve kept my own past fairly
>   private.

**And a kind of superspace**
:

> Hyperspace, where the Newtonian and Einsteinian rules break down, is
>   the rind of the orange. Fine and dandy. Now friend Diekereide grips
>   the orange like a baseball and throws the hard slider. He tells me the
>   rind exists everywhere coequal with the universe it contains. An
>   orange that is part rind all the way to the pips. Relates back to the
>   curvature of space, where, if you head off on a straight line and
>   stick with it long enough, you get back to where you started. Only,
>   using Reinhardt’s math, you can take shortcuts because in hyperspace
>   every point touches every other point. In perfect hyperspace, which
>   seems to be as mythical as perfect vacuum, you can travel the light
>   years between point A and point B in no elapsed time.